# ASP.NET MVC BaseController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use a BaseController to wire up my service layer. All other controllers inherit this controller. Now I'm embarking on building an MVC2 project template. I would like controllers to inherit this by default, not just the ": Controller", but have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom t4 templates to do this

http://www.davidhayden.me/2009/11/aspnet-mvc-and-t4-templates-generating-controllers-and-views.html

Comment: Completely awesome the power of code templates. Thank you very much and I find myself wondering how much time I've lost coding over the years...

Answer (score 1):

I'd note that if it is just to wire in a service layer, you might well be better served by using an IoC container (eg--structuremap) and dependency injection into otherwise unadulterated Controllers. Or, Composition > Inheritance any day.